# Capture Facebook start page https with Fiddler and Firefox

Tags: fiddler

I try to capture Facebook start page (https://www.facebook.com/) with Fiddler.
Fiddler is configured properly for https: I can capture the facebook traffic with Chrome and IE.

However if I try to do this with FF (latest 19.0.2) the page renders partially possible because of javascript errors. The Fiddler certificate below Fiddler's DO NOT TRUST root is installed correctly.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, it appears that you've configured a **certificate exception** for Facebook.com specifically, but most of Facebook's assets aren't actually on that domain. Instead of doing that, instead configure Firefox to **trust the Fiddler root certificate**:

1> In Fiddler, choose Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Export Root Certificate to desktop.

2> In Firefox, choose Tools > Firefox Options > Advanced > Encryption > Certificates > Authorities > Import and import the FiddlerRoot.cer file from your desktop.